# Is the transformer working and possible identification

Tags: transformer

Unfortunately 2 nights ago, my 120V stereo was plugged into a 220V socket directly.
(I'm just about talking to the offender again).

The stereo now ceases to function more or less

- Radio, tape player, amplifier and lights not working
- Only the record platter turns (I know the record player is 120V).
- There was a burning chemical smell afterwards.

Unfortunately I have being unable to track down a service manual or schematic for the stereo. So I don't know what is supplied by the transformer inside...but as the record platter and tone arm continues to function, I'm wondering if the transformer is step down and powers the radio, tape player, amplifier and lights. This is my theory as of now anyway.

The transformer...

- It's labelled as AC-159C (but I cannot find any reference to this on the Internet).
- There are 2 wires (both white) on one side which I am assuming are the input wires.
- There are 5 wires (2 x red, 1 x black, 1 x green and 1 x yellow) on the other side which I am assuming are the output wires.
- I've been unable to find any specifications on it or the stereo so I'm not sure what the voltages should be.

**So my 2 questions are...**

1. Can anyone identify the transformer?
2. There is no resistance measurement between the two white wires. Is my transformer working? Or are there other tests I should perform? (details of testing below).

**Transformer test:** I removed the transformer from the stereo and tested the resistance between all the wires.

- White -> White = No measurement (Open circuit I assume)
- White wires to all other wires = No measurement (Open circuit I assume)
- Red (#1) -> Red (#2) = 3ohms
- Red (#1) -> Yellow = 2.2ohms
- Red (#1) -> Green = 3.2ohms
- Red (#1) -> Black = 3ohms
- Red (#2) -> Yellow = 2.1ohms
- Red (#2) -> Green = 3.2ohms
- Red (#2) -> Black = 3.2ohms
- Yellow -> Green = 1.6ohms
- Yellow -> Black = 0.9ohms
- Green -> Black = 1.9ohms

  [image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Are you sure the transformer failed and not (just) the capacitors downstream of it? Potentially some transistors too. _"AC-159C"_ Most likely custom. Can you post a picture of it?

Comment: Why are the 120V plugs the same as the 220V plugs? Or was this a bare wires and matchsticks job?

Comment: More information would be really helpful.  Things like make/model number and a photo of the transformer.  But I'm guessing the two white wires are the mains input.  If so and they read an open circuit, you've killed the primary of the transformer.  You might check to see if the manufacturer offers spare parts.  Often consumer products use CUSTOM components which are difficult to cross-source.

Comment: Hello and thank you all for responding. To answer your questions...the offender had the wherewithal to source an adaptor plug butt not a transformer before plugging it in (sigh). I am not sure that the issue is the transformer but I chose to test it first as the electronics is very compacted into a small space and the transformer has what looked like a hardened resin on parts of the outside which caught my eye. I have since learned that this could be simply a badly applied varnish. I tried previously to post phots but they were too large. I will try again now.

Comment: I also chose to go at the transformer first as my ability is fairly limited and the transformer seemed easy to test.

Comment: The stereo is labelled 'Planetron 2000' but I believe it is also known as a Brother Primus II and as a Brother Charisma II and even possibly a Brother BR-5. It says it is made in the USA but I believe it was just branded there and was more or less manufactured in Japan. The stereo has a lot of similarities in design ideas to the more famous Weltron brand.

Comment: I have tried to contact Brother International Corporation looking for schematics but have yet to receive a response. From what I can see they left the stereo business a long time ago. I've also posted on a HiFi web forums looking for info but so far there's no feedback. The stereo was never sold in large numbers as far as I can make out.

Comment: On the testing side, there is one update. I can confirm that the feed into the 2 white wires is 116V AC. Which I guess confirms that this is the primary side. The fact that I cannot measure a resistance across the two white wires seems to indicate that the primary side is fried. I would happily buy a replacement transformer if only I could determine what I needed! I'm also aware of the possibility that there could be other issues (like capacitors)...but one step at a time...

Comment: I have added a photo of the transformer to the original post.

Comment: One would expect the white wires to be the primary, judging from the picture. If those are open circuit then the winding is open and the transformer is broken. Could either be the winding itself that burned trough, or a thermal fuse that's packed in between the winding.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. I have tested the transformer outputs and there are no voltage readings off any of the wires, so this along with the fact that I'm getting an open circuits across the input has convinced me that the transformer is kaput. Thus far, I am unable to determine what the transformer make/model/specs are, so I may be forced to try and repair it. I am hoping that I find a burnt out fuse. The outerbody (see photo) seems to be glued on. I imagine transformers get quite hot. Do you  know what kind of glue/sealant is used on them? Thanks.